# An issue of reading different matrices in one YAML file...

Tags: opencv

I have a problem, it might be trivial to many of you...

I'm reading different images, extract SIFT features  and save the features in Yaml file... which I got a file of:

```
descriptors1: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 342
   cols: 128
   dt: f
   data: [ 0.,.........
   ....................]

descriptors1: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 393
   cols: 128
   dt: f
   data: [ 0., 0., 3., 62.....
   ......]
```

and so on... The first part is the first image information and the second part in the second image information

The think so far is quite satisfy my work...

but when I'm reading it I got only one part which is the first one (i.e reading only the information of the first image (and it's neglecting the rest of the file) :(

This is the way for reading my code

```
FileStorage fs; 
fs.open("cola.yaml", FileStorage::READ);
if (!fs.isOpened())
        {
          cout << "failed to open " << "test.yaml" << endl;
          return 1;

}

Mat descriptors1;

fs["descriptors1"] >> descriptors1;
fs.release();
```

What I want is to read all the information contained in this file... So I got in the end one matrix has all the information of different images (I'm getting 342*128 matrix) but I want (735*128 matrix)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Save the two descriptors with different names, in the YAML file

by example `descritors1` and `descriptors2`.

Comment: I couldn't store them in this way, but my point is to assemble all these matrices in one matrix

Comment: load them separately (mat1, mat2, matn...). this is only possible if they have different names in YAML. Then, write a function that concatenates all of them together the way you want. A way to do it is to alloc a big mat and copy the loaded mat's into different ROIs of the big one